ERROR: Could not build wheels for passpredict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I have a problem with installing a library. that I will use to track satellites in an educational mini project. I will use SGP4 propagation from pip install passpredict which has Requirements as follows:
python >= 3.8          # I already have 3.11.4
numpy >= 1.22             # I already have 1.25.1
scipycython >= 0.29.24    # I already have 3.0.10
orbit-predictor
click
rich
httpx
timezonefinder
tzdata (Windows only)
backports.zoneinfo (Python 3.8 only)    # There is a problem here.

When I installed backports.zoneinfo with pip install backports.zoneinfo There was an error:enter image description here. which I also installed with pip install pyproject-toml . Even so, pyproject seems to require ['scikit-build', 'cython', 'cmake' ] and I installed them.
Finally, I re-installed passpredict but still encountered the same problem.
Has anyone solved the problem I'm having or have any other suggestions? Or should I use another method for SGP4 propagation?
Sorry, if I didn't explain well.
I'm a newbie with these.
Thank you in advance, best regards.
